# How i can display child records from corresponding parent id in angular js

Tags: angularjs

i have one list of data like below picture. 
[image]

In that table we can see child menu, in that column "3 dots available"that mean if any row have child rows for corresponding column then "3 dots available" available. Now i want to do like when i click on "3 dots" need to redirect another page and need to display the corresponding row records.

i did like this when i click on "3 dots" then all child rows is coming, you can see the below picture.
[image]

but i couldn't able to do like when i click on "3 dots" need do display only corresponding child records only

but i couldn't able to do like when i click on "3 dots" need do display only corresponding child records only.
**Example:** If i click on "3 dots" in child columns for Analytics column in Image 1, then need to display the child records for Analytics only no need for all sub child.

Code for First Image

```
       <tr>
        <th>Sr. No.</th>
        <th>Menu Name</th>
        <th>Enabled</th>
        <th>Child Menu</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="menus in menuList" >
    <td >{{$index+1}}</td>
    <td >{{menus.menu}}</td>
    <td>{{menus.enable}}</td>
    <td ng-if="menus.menu_items"><span class="text-left logo-dashboard">
    <a ui-sref="configureChildMenuState"title="Cilk me"><span     class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal"></span></a>
   </td>
   <td ng-if="!menus.menu_items"></td>

</tr>
```

for second image2

```
     <tr>
        <th>Sr. No.</th>
        <th>Parent Id</th>
        <th>Original Label</th>
        <th>New Label</th>
        <th>Url</th>
        <th>Enable</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="ChildMenu in ChildMenuList" >
    <td >{{$index+1}}</td>
    <td>{{ChildMenu.menu_id}}</td>
    <td >{{ChildMenu.original_label}}</td>
    <td >{{ChildMenu.new_label}}</td>
    <td >{{ChildMenu.url}}</td>
    <td >{{ChildMenu.enabled}}</td>
    <td>
    <a class="edit-icon" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalEdit" ng-click="getData(store)"><img src="../app/img/edit-icon.png" alt="Edit"></a>
   </td>


</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that depends on your object.

if you can share the iterating object, i could help you